# Как сохранить в переменную урл файла без расширения?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Необходимо в конфиг файле nginx взять урл файла без расширения:

```
example.com/product/image.jpg => example.com/product/image
```

Comment: Куда взять? Чем взять?

Comment: Ну это я и спрашиваю.
К примеру, мне нужно, сделать редирект с path/somefile.ext на path/somefile, или эта примитивная задача из области фантастики?

Comment: Нет, вы спрашиваете совсем не это, а непонятно что. Читаете строчку и отрезаете последние символы.

Comment: куда взять - написано в заголовке вопроса

Comment: Как взять - я написал в комментарии.

Comment: Зачем? Опишите что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Эникейщик, Спасибо Кэп!

Comment: У меня есть проверка файла на расширение, если это картинка ( jpg, png ), то я смотрю такую-же только .webp - иначе отдаю jpg/png, Вот. У меня в переменной $webp_ext лежит '.webp' и мне нужно склеить это с строкой запроса файла только без расширения jpg/png

Comment: По идее у Вас картинки должны быть что то типа `test.jpg` и  `test.jpg.webp`,  а не  `test.jpg` и `test.webp`

Comment: на serverfalaut усть подобный [вопрос](https://serverfault.com/questions/810693/nginx-rule-to-serve-webp-images-when-available)

Comment: по сути Вы берете в скобки часть путь регулярки без разрешения  ( `location ^(/images)\.(jpe?g|png)$`  ) и это будет `$1`

Comment: если картинки хранить как image.jpg.webp то собсно это решение, но не по фен-шую)